# Using `quote()` function in R to generate a multivariable expression

Tags: r

I am attempting to generate a simple multivariable expression in R that is similar to the following:

```r
coef1 * prev1 + coef2 * prev2 + coef3 * prev3
```

I can do this easily with `quote()`

```
quote(coef1 * prev1 + coef2 * prev2 + coef3 * prev3)
```

which generates the desired `call` class.

The issue arises when I have multiple coefficients (i.e., multiple `coef`) to estimate.

I could do this using `paste0()`

```
myvec <- 1:3

paste0(paste0("coef",myvec,"*prev",myvec),collapse="+")
#> [1] "coef1*prev1+coef2*prev2+coef3*prev3"
```

But the issue is that the class of the above is a `character`. Using `quote()`, the class is `call` which can be used to be evaluated.

I also cannot wrap the above in `quote` because the `paste0` function will be included in the expression:

```
quote(paste0(paste0("coef",myvec,"*prev",myvec),collapse="+"))
```

will give:

```r
paste0(paste0("coef", myvec, "*prev", myvec), collapse = "+")
```

when all I want is:

```
coef1 * prev1 + coef2 * prev2 + coef3 * prev3
```

Is there any possible way to still generate a `call` class with multiple variables to estimate without having to explicitly type them all in `quote`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This expression looks like it should be expressed as a matrix multiplication, i.e., `prev %*% coef`, where `prev` is a matrix and `coef` is a vector (or matrix). What do you need the expression for? There might be better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str2lang` instead of `quote`

```r
myvec <- 1:3

mycall <- str2lang(paste0(paste0("coef", myvec, "*prev", myvec), collapse = "+"))

mycall
#> coef1 * prev1 + coef2 * prev2 + coef3 * prev3

class(mycall)
#> [1] "call"
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about `str2lang`. Thank you very much!